# Libre Office - Create chart

Tags: libreoffice

I have some data that I have to represent using calc.

If I select two columns that are next to each other (`$mergesort.$A$1:$B$101`) the plot is created without any problem.

However, I want to select data from different plots. According to the [official website](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Chart_Wizard_-_Data_Range)
I should use a semicolon and select the columns in this way :

```
$mergesort.$A$1:$A$101;$mergesort.$C$1:$C$101
```

However, when I add this thing as my datarange, the OK button at the dialog box gets deactivated and the text box turns to red. This happens just after I add a semicolon at the already selected area.

Am I doing something wrong?

By the way, I do not know if this plays any important role, but my chart is a line graph, and I also have data in both columns A and C

My problem is also shown at the screenshots below

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, the mistake is at their documentation. It works perfectly (at least for me) when a comma is used instead of a semicolon

Comment: That might depend on your language / locale settings. Check your preferences/options/settings - especially in calc. The same is valid/necessary in Windows/Office - there are way too many options in my opinion: I'm for "Keep it simple"; NO thousands separator (looks pretty, but useless from other aspects), decimal POINT in numbers, comma is item separator in lists, semicolon and colon has special uses - don't set them for anything special. unambiguous dates are YYYY-MM-DD nothing else. Result - a lot less confusion.